# How to reset CKeditor4 with SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, sweetalert2

I am using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) for a form. I want when a user click on `Reset` button that sweetalert appears. I have done all work popup is appearing and some of fields are reset but the problem is with **CKeditor4** it's not reseting. Usually I am using (given below) script for reseting CKeditor:
**JS**

```
$(function() {
    if (typeof CKEDITOR != 'undefined') {
        $('form').on('reset', function(e) {
            if ($(CKEDITOR.instances).length) {
                for (var key in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                    var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[key];
                    if ($(instance.element.$).closest('form').attr('name') == $(e.target).attr('name')) {
                        instance.setData(instance.element.$.defaultValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the working Fiddle in which other fields are reseting but not ckeditor, how can I do that. [**Click to see Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mhkdotme/x5nLm80e/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See update [at this updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83p5o2v8/).

Adding the following should do it (Borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087037/reset-ckeditor-value-on-form-reset-button):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1
   .setData( '', function() { this.updateElement(); } );
```